# Determine whether $X$ and $Y$ are statistically independent.

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, independence

My homework problem asks me to determine if the random variables $X$ and $Y$ are statistically independent, given their joint density function:

[image]

This is only true if $f(x,y) = f_X(x)f_Y(y)$, where the subscripted functions are the marginal distributions of $X$ and $Y$, respectively. Here is a screenshot of my work in MS Word:

[image]

Part of me suspects this is wrong. Is my work correct? If so, **please don't tell me the correct steps to take. Rather, offer some hints to push me in the right direction so I can solve it on my own.** Thank you! :)

Comment: It seems right to me.

Comment: And to me, too.

Comment: Alright, thank you both for verifying!